# SQL Oracle join prob with tables not joining

Tags: sql, oracle

I think problem is my join somewhere
my OrderID are not together

I dont know how to fix it

```
select l.orderid, sum(l.qty) as units_sold, sum (l.qty) * p.price as Sales_Amount
from order_lines l join
     products p
     on p.prodid = l.prodid
group by l.orderid, p.price
Order by sum(l.qty) * p.price
```

Kinda like the out put. 231 not joined

```
OrderID.          Units sold.       Price
231.                       5.                   5
243.                        6.                   6
246.                        7.                   7
231.                        8.                    8
247.                        6.                     9
```

Comment: you cannot do aggregation in order by. Order by is the last thing to be executed in a query. You must specify a column on the basis of which to order.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you actually want:

```
select l.orderid, sum(l.qty) as units_sold, sum(l.qty * p.price) as Sales_Amount
from order_lines l join
     products p
     on p.prodid = l.prodid
group by l.orderid
Order by Sales_Amount ;
```

The `group by` clause specifies how you want to define the rows in the result set.  If you want only one row per `orderid`, then you should have only `orderid` in the `group by`.